# Android bluetooth a2dp and spp in same time is possible? Aka Audio and data in same time

Tags: android, audio, spp, a2dp

Hello i use bk8000l chip which according with specifications support spp and a2dp in same time. I need to find/build an app that is sendind some spp commands and also voice from phone mic. Is a ptt (push-to-talk). The data is necessary to be received by a pic cpu on serial port to start /stop transmission on transceiver side bi pressing/releasing a button on phone. Audio is obviously for what is needed i think. Please give me some ideas thank you.